# Can I refer to "ThisBundle" in a twig template, instead of hardcoding a bundle name?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'd like to be able to implicitly refer to the current bundle from within a twig template; normally you'd see:

```
{% stylesheets '@AppBundle/Resources/public/css/main.css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
…
{%- include 'AppBundle:Alpha:nav.html.twig' -%}
```

But, instead of harcoding **AppBundle** I'd like to generically say **ThisBundle**:

```
{% stylesheets '@ThisBundle/Resources/public/css/main.css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
…
{%- include 'ThisBundle:Alpha:nav.html.twig' -%}
```

Is something along these lines currently possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can do this.  Start by reading: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html

The twig name space processor does not actually care (or even really know about) bundles.  Instead,  it maintains an array which maps @whatever to one or more location where it looks for the desired file.

By default,  the symfony TwigBundle:DependencyInjection:TwigExtension class adds all the existing bundles to this array.  It's instructive to review the code.

All you really need to do is to add your paths to config.yml

```
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
    paths:
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/Cerad/Bundle/AppBundle/Resources/views": ThisBundle
```

Of course there is really no such thing as a "current" bundle.  You still need to set the resource path as shown above.  But I'm pretty sure this will suit your needs.

Sorry for all the edits.  For this to work you do need to use twig namespaces exclusively.  So something like:

```
{%- include '@ThisBundle/Alpha/nav.html.twig' -%}
```

Comment: @MarkFox wanted to use `@ThisBundle` to refer to the current bundle

Comment: Correct.  So all he needs to do is to map ThisBundle to whatever directory the "Current" bundle resources live.  He really does not mention what "current bundle" really means.  I'm pretty sure he just wants a bit of abstraction.  We shall see.

Comment: This answer is a nice compromise and could work nicely for this problem or similar issues of abstracting naming dependencies; it's definitely not a perfect fit since it's a global name…

Comment: What would be a perfect fit?  Where would you want to load nav.html.twig from?

Comment: @Cerad Perfect fit for him would be option to make "@ThisBundle" **always** search for asset inside the same bundle in which template is. So, for "MyBundle1" `@ThisBundle/my_css.css` would actually mean `@MyBundle1/my_css.css`, but for template in "MyBundle2" that same "path" would mean `MyBundle2/my_css.css`

Comment: But how would you know which bundle nav.html.twig is in?  It could be in a different bundle than what the template including it is in.  If the controller knows then just have it pass the namespace as a value.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand your answer, this doesn't change the fact that it is not possible to refer to the current bundle in a template. It merely creates a sort of alias for a specific bundle.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible.

However, you could make a `CoreBundle` where you store generic templates like navigation and site-wide stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. And there really is no real use case in which you should be able to do this. A bundle knows it's own name, as it knows it's bundle class (which is the name) and at least it knows the namespace, which is the bundle name... There is no way to change the bundle name without changing the bundle.